# aclocal/autoconf reports missing m4sugar.m4 on Mac OS X?

Tags: xcode, autoconf, m4

I have Xcode 3.2 installed into /Xcode3.2, and did *not* install anything into /Developer. When I wish to do development, I start up a shell as follows

```
alias sysroot='PATH=${PATH}:${XCODE}/usr/bin CFLAGS=--sysroot\ ${SDK_ROOT} CXXFLAGS=--sysroot\ ${SDK_ROOT} LDFLAGS=--sysroot\ ${SDK_ROOT} CPPFLAGS=--sysroot\ ${SDK_ROOT}'
```

where `XCODE` is `/Xcode3.2` and `SDK_ROOT` is `${XCODE}/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk`. This handles most of the oddities of trying to build projects. However, I recently ran into a case where I wanted to re-run `aclocal` and got the following error:

```
autom4te: m4sugar/m4sugar.m4: no such file or directory
aclocal: /Xcode3.2/usr/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 1
```

Specifying `-I` flags to `aclocal` to point at the alternative `/Xcode3.2/usr/share/aclocal-1.10` and `/Xcode3.2/usr/share/aclocal` doesn't seem to help. If I use `--verbose`, and then re-run the `m4` command it lists manually with an added `-I` flag to point to `/Xcode3.2/usr/share/autoconf`, then that works, but I cannot seem to pipe it through from `aclocal`. In addition the `M4PATH` environment variable that the `man` pages for `m4` suggest will let me add paths does not seem to make a difference. (And setting an environment variable would be my preferred setting, just so I could add it to the alias above.)

So far, I've not come up with a solution other than the "dirtying" procedure of creating a symlink from `/usr/share/autoconf` to `/Xcode3.2/usr/share/autoconf`. Is there another better way?

NOTE: The reason I keep such distinct lines between installs of the developer tools and the OS is to provide reliable cross-OS compilations (e.g., so that one Xcode version's tools don't perturb another Xcode version's build behavior.)

Answer (score 8):

I got around this by creating a new symlink

```
sudo ln -s  /Developer/usr/share/autoconf /usr/share
```

Answer (score 7):

To clarify the fix as identified in adl's answer and Nathan's comment on it:

If you have `autoconf` installed in the default location (under `/Developer`) as part of XCode 4.3, you'll need to edit `/Developer/usr/share/autoconf/autom4te.cfg` as it has various wrong paths set it in that don't include the `/Developer` directory:

(The edits are illustrated as some kind of diff that I found in the Google [cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3agzkyMKJpyoQJ%3atech.chickenandporn.com/2011/10/28/xcode-4-2-breaks-automake-autoconf-autoreconf-aclocal/%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a) of [this post](http://tech.chickenandporn.com/2011/10/28/xcode-4-2-breaks-automake-autoconf-autoreconf-aclocal/))

```
*** /Developer/usr/share/autoconf/autom4te.cfg 2011-10-28 00:15:15.000000000 -0700
--- /Developer/usr/share/autoconf/autom4te.cfg 2011-10-28 00:14:33.000000000 -0700
***************
*** 99,101 ****
begin-language: "Autoconf-without-aclocal-m4"
! args: --prepend-include /usr/share/autoconf
args: --cache=autom4te.cache
--- 99,101 ----
begin-language: "Autoconf-without-aclocal-m4"
! args: --prepend-include /Developer/usr/share/autoconf
args: --cache=autom4te.cache
***************
*** 126,128 ****
begin-language: "Autotest"
! args: --prepend-include /usr/share/autoconf
args: autotest/autotest.m4f
--- 126,128 ----
begin-language: "Autotest"
! args: --prepend-include /Developer/usr/share/autoconf
args: autotest/autotest.m4f
***************
*** 140,142 ****
begin-language: "M4sh"
! args: --prepend-include /usr/share/autoconf
args: m4sugar/m4sh.m4f
--- 140,142 ----
begin-language: "M4sh"
! args: --prepend-include /Developer/usr/share/autoconf
args: m4sugar/m4sh.m4f
***************
*** 152,154 ****
begin-language: "M4sugar"
! args: --prepend-include /usr/share/autoconf
args: m4sugar/m4sugar.m4f
--- 152,154 ----
begin-language: "M4sugar"
! args: --prepend-include /Developer/usr/share/autoconf
args: m4sugar/m4sugar.m4f
```

Comment: Under xcode 6 and OSX 10.9.4 did not work but this post and previous posts gave valuable clues. What did work is: brew uninstall autoconf then brew install autoconf which gave a few instructions and then I have executed  brew link --overwrite autoconf. Under OSX 10.9.4 there was no /Developer/usr/share/autoconf because it under /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand what in your setup causes `autom4te` not to find the file.  Did you move `autom4te` to the directory `Xcode3.2/` after it was initially installed in `/usr/bin/`? It's not clear to me from your question (I'm not familiar with Xcode, is that bundled with autoconf?).

Anyway... The location where `autom4te` looks for `m4sugar.m4` is hardcoded in `autom4te` when the Autoconf package is installed.   In fact it is even more subtle: the search path is configured in `DATADIR/autom4te.cfg`, but the value of DATADIR is hardcoded into `autom4te`.  You can change the value of DATADIR by setting an environment variable like `export AC_MACRODIR=/Xcode3.2/usr/share/autoconf`, but if you moved `/usr/share/autoconf/autom4te.cfg` to `/Xcode3.2/usr/share/autoconf/autom4te.cfg`, the contents of that file will still point to `/usr/share/autoconf/`.

You could have a local `~/.autom4te.cfg` to add more `--prepend-include` lines, but this is crude as well.  IMHO the simplest solution if you want Autoconf installed in `Xcode3.2/` is to install it with `./configure --prefix /Xcode3.2 && make && make install`.  It takes less half  a minute.

Comment: autom4te and m4 and all of these tools are installed along with Xcode when you install the Apple-provided developer tools on Mac OS X. This vs. installing all of them via fink or darwinports etc. You can elect to have them place helpful copies (perhaps links?) in /usr/whatever, but they all live in /Xcode3.2- or /Developer-prefixed paths instead. Thus, I am not responsible for the configuration of autoconf -- it is all Apple. It appears they need to be parameterizing their autom4te.cfg when they install it in a non-standard location (e.g., /Xcode3.2). Fixing that .cfg makes it work. Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion bug to parameterize their autom4te.cfg paths has been filed as rdar://9454686.

Answer (score 1):

In the Xcode4 environment:

```
sudo ln -s /Xcode4/usr/share/autoconf /usr/share/autoconf
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used MacPorts for installing much, you probably have an installation of autoconf which will then add in autom4te and start messing with your paths. If, like me, you are moving from MacPorts then you'll need to uninstall autoconf ( `sudo port uninstall autoconf` ) before making edits like the ones suggested by Ergwun